# How can I retrieve the custom activity name in Journey Builder using JavaScript?

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, journeybuilder, custom-activity

I'm currently working on a collaboration.
In our company, we want to set the custom activity name that is configured to be visible when opening the activity in Journey Builder as the default value in the "Activity name" field when we open the activity.

How can I retrieve the value from the Journey Builder screen using JavaScript?

I'll be waiting for your help